# WPF UniformGrid dynamic row height

Tags: c#, wpf, height, uniformgrid

I wrote a little application which display some images. For this I used a `UniformGrid`. My `xaml`-Code:

```html
<ScrollViewer>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Name="unifomGrid" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" IsItemsHost="True" Loaded="unifomGrid_Loaded" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32px" Margin="8px">
          <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
              <Image Source="{Binding Path, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

My problem is, that the row height of the `UniformGrid` isn't dynamic. Is there any possibility that every row got his own row height? Currently the height of each row is the height of the highest element inside the `UniformGrid`.

Comment: What is your issue? How do you expect your UI to look like?

Comment: @mm8 take a look on the image. The second marked place. The space between the two images (upper one and lower one) should be 16px too.

Comment: As MSDN states, UniformGrid "_provides a way to arrange content in a grid where all the cells in the grid have the **same** size_" so probably it is not the control that you need.

Comment: Please read this and modify your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: DId you try to use a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate instead of a UniformGrid?

Comment: @mm8 yes, but I am struggling with it, because the WrapPanel won't fill the available space. For example the window has a width of 600px and the items inside the WrapPanel have a MinWidth of 200px and a MaxWidth of 250px. At the end there will be 2 items each with a width of 200px. And at the right side is a white stripe of 100px.

Comment: Can't you bind the Width of the WrapPanel to the the ActualWidth of the parent panel/window?

Comment: @mm8 okay. I've tried it now. The WrapPanel take the size of the window, but the items inside the WrapPanel dosen't fill the remaining space. Still the same result with the white strip at the right side.

Comment: As mentioned, you should provide a full repo of your issue.

Comment: there is no way to make a uniform grid have different cell sizes. you should try grid

Comment: None of the existing WPF panels fits your needs. Why do you avoid implementing of custom panel? In your case it will be very easy since the desired logic is not complex.

Comment: @Maxim never did it before. Do you know a page which explain this procedure?

Comment: @MyNewName You can start from [this](http://putridparrot.com/blog/creating-a-custom-panel-using-wpf/) small blog post. In `ArrangeOverride` you just need calculate right X, Y coordinates of the point to place an element at for each element in the panel. In your case these calculations are super easy. Custom panels is the key to solve many UI related problems in WPF, so I highly recommend to learn it :)

Comment: @Maxim thanks for the answer! I will start at this point. I have on more question. In case I get it work and I have 400 images added. Will the performance be okay?

Comment: It needs to be checked. But all standard WPF panels are built with this technique (you can view [source code of the UniformGrid](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/UniformGrid.cs), for example) and have more complex logic than your panel. So your panel definitely will not lose in performance in comparison with standard panels.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different route you might take a look at. It uses a grid instead and uses the [GridHelpers](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) class to allow you to do what you're looking for as the default Height for each Row is set to Auto.

```
 <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                <ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid
                            IsItemsHost="True"
                            Loaded="Grid_Loaded"
                            GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Template>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32px" Margin="8px">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </materialDesign:Card>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
```